# Symfony Api Post/Put Entity ManyToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I have endpoint post teams in api. Entity teams have relation entity rank, ManyToMAny and in form, when I create team I add rank entity and doctrine does all the work for me - flush entity. But I have api and use JMS Serializer . How to flush entity teams in api with help form???
entity teams

```
class Teams
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Groups({"for_chat", "get_team", "for_sample_set", "for_sample", "for_team_members", "for_profile_project", "for_all_projects"})
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Groups({"get_team"})
 */
protected $slug;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Rank", inversedBy="teams")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="rank_teams")
 * @Groups({"get_team"})
 */
private $rank;
```

runk

```
class Rank
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @Groups({"get_team"})
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Teams", mappedBy="rank")
 */
private $teams;
```

in form addd entity runk

```
        $form->add('rank', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'ArtelProfileBundle:Rank',
        'property' => 'name',
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'required' => false,
    ));
```

now how I post entity team

```
    /**
 * Post Team,.
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 * resource = true,
 * description = "Post Team",
 *  parameters={
 *      {"name"="image_back", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="image_back"},
 *      {"name"="name", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="name"},
 *      {"name"="description", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="description"},
 *      {"name"="image", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="image"},
 *      {"name"="profile_summary", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="profile_summary"},
 *      {"name"="web_site", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="web_site"},
 *      {"name"="markets", "dataType"="array", "required"=false, "description"="markets"},
 *      {"name"="skills", "dataType"="array", "required"=false, "description"="skills"},
 *      {"name"="city", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="location teams"},
 *      {"name"="ranks", "dataType"="array", "required"=false, "description"="rank"},
 *      {"name"="avalible_from", "dataType"="date", "required"=false, "description"="avalible_from like 2013-07-21T01:16:22-0500"},
 *      {"name"="avalible_to", "dataType"="date", "required"=false, "description"="avalible_to like 2013-07-21T01:16:22-0500"},
 *      {"name"="token", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="is equally md5('email'.secret_word)"}
 *  },
 * statusCodes = {
 *      200 = "Returned when successful",
 *      400 = "Secret token is not valid"
 * },
 * section="Team"
 * )
 *
 * @RestView()
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return View
 *
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException when not exist
 */
public function postTeamAction(Request $request)
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $token = $this->get('request')->request->get('token');
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Users')->findOneBySecuritytoken($token);

    if (!empty($user) && !empty($token)) {
        $team = new Teams();
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $data = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($data, 'json');
        $team = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize($data, 'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Teams', 'json');

        if (count($errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($team)) > 0) {
            $view = $this->view((string) $errors, 400);

            return $this->handleView($view);
        }

        if (!is_null($this->get('request')->request->get('city'))) {
            $nameCity = $this->get('request')->request->get('city');
            $city = $this->get('artel.profile.additional_function')->addCityAction($nameCity);
            $team->setLocation($city);
        }

        if (!is_null($this->get('request')->request->get('ranks'))) {
            $ranks = $this->get('request')->request->get('ranks');
            foreach($ranks as $rank){
                $rankEntity = $this->get('artel.profile.additional_function')->checkRank($rank);
                $team->addRank($rankEntity);
            }
        }

        $manager->persist($team);
        $user->setTeams($team);
        $manager->flush();

        $view = $this->view('Team successful create', 200);

        return $this->handleView($view);
    } else {
        $view = $this->view('Secret token is not valid', 400);

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

but JMS Serializer dont know about ManyToMany rank. For ManyToOne city I add like this

```
            if (!is_null($this->get('request')->request->get('city'))) {
            $nameCity = $this->get('request')->request->get('city');
            $city = $this->get('artel.profile.additional_function')->addCityAction($nameCity);
            $team->setLocation($city);
        }
```

where $city this is entity city, I check if already and return or create new and return. But this is custom method not wotk with ManyToMany. And I create something like that

```
            if (!is_null($this->get('request')->request->get('ranks'))) {
            $ranks = $this->get('request')->request->get('ranks');
            foreach($ranks as $rank){
                $rankEntity = $this->get('artel.profile.additional_function')->checkRank($rank);
                $team->addRank($rankEntity);
            }
        }
```

but this is method not universal this is good only for post.  If I use PUT this is methods not deleted rank automatic like doctrine with form. Example I have two rank but in edit in form I select one - doctrine automatic deleted and automatic add entity runk

How to flush entity teams with ManyToMany runk with help forms, because with forms work fine